# iTunes Connect API to access list of IAPs

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Is there a web based API that allows me to retrieve a list of available IAP including the prices in the different tiers. My scenario is that a server application needs to retrieve a the list of products including their relevant prices from iTunes Connect.

Comment: This looks promising: https://github.com/fastlane/itc-api-docs

Comment: Unfortunately not: https://github.com/fastlane/itc-api-docs/issues/6 :(